# Allowed memory size exhausted, tried to allocate xx bytes

Tags: php, memory

In an error log file on my server are some errors of this kind :

- PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
  (tried to allocate 86 bytes) in ....(a php file, on line..)
- PHP Fatal    error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
  (tried to    allocate 2 bytes) in ....(a php file, on line..)

For every error the recommended allocate bytes amount is lower than 100 bytes.

Does it mean that an increase of memory of only 100 bytes would solve every problem ?

How could I know what script is responsible for so much memory usage ?

My shop is built with Prestashop 1.5.6.2.

The full error message that I get is the following :

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92 bytes) in ../classes/db/DbPDO.php on line 101
```

The line 101 is as follows :

```
return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This line is part of the following code :

```
    public function nextRow($result = false)
{
    if (!$result)
        $result = $this->result;
    return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I am not a developer and I thank you in advance for any help in this matter.

Patrick

I thank you in advance for any reply.

Patrick

Comment: No! The best way to solve the problem is to work out why the script needs so much memory, and then change the way it works so that it doesn't require that much any more

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a developer. What could I do to know why the script need so much memory ? Thank you advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to increase you PHP memory limit. You can do this by adding the following code to the top of your file

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

Or increasing it in your php.ini file

```
memory_limit = 512M;
```

If you don't have access to that you can add this to your .htaccess file

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, my Host Provider does not allow a memory limit higher than 256 Mo.

Comment: I edited my question 2 days ago. Would anyone has any idea to solve the matter without increasing the memory limit ?

Comment: Are you hosting on their severs or somewhere else?

Comment: My hosting provider is Gandi : https://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/php/phpini